# regex approach to capture both 1-word and 2-word Proper Nouns

Tags: python, regex

I've come up with the below. I've narrowed down the problem to the inability to capture both 1-word and 2-word proper nouns.

(1) It would be great if i could put in a condition that instructs a default to the longer word when given a choice between two captures.

AND

(2) if I could tell the regex to only consider this if the string starts with a prepositoin, such as On|At|For. I was playing around with something like this but it isn't working:

```
(^On|^at)([A-Z][a-z]{3,15}$|[A-Z][a-z]{3,15}\s{0,1}[A-Z][a-z]{0,5})
```

How would I do 1 and 2?

my current regex

```
r'([A-Z][a-z]{3,15}$|[A-Z][a-z]{3,15}\s{0,1}[A-Z][a-z]{0,15})'
```

I'd like to capture, Ashoka, Shift Series, Compass Partners, and Kenneth Cole

```
#'On its 25th anniversary, Ashoka',

#'at the Shift Series national conference, Compass Partners and fashion designer Kenneth Cole',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do here is called "named entity recognition" in natural language processing. If you really want an approach that will find proper nouns, then you may have to consider stepping up to named entity recognition. Thankfully there's some easy to use functions in the `nltk` library:

```
import nltk
s2 = 'at the Shift Series national conference, Compass Partners and fashion designer Kenneth Cole'
tokens2 = nltk.word_tokenize(s2)
tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens2)
res = nltk.ne_chunk(tags)
```

Results:

```
res.productions()
Out[8]: 
[S -> ('at', 'IN') ('the', 'DT') ORGANIZATION ('national', 'JJ') ('conference', 'NN') (',', ',') ORGANIZATION ('and', 'CC') ('fashion', 'NN') ('designer', 'NN') PERSON,
 ORGANIZATION -> ('Shift', 'NNP') ('Series', 'NNP'),
 ORGANIZATION -> ('Compass', 'NNP') ('Partners', 'NNPS'),
 PERSON -> ('Kenneth', 'NNP') ('Cole', 'NNP')]
```

Comment: Ah ic, this is really useful. I'll consider just doing this then. How would you grab just ORGANIZATION AND PERSON? I'm not clear how to use this tree format.

Comment: actually got it. for subtree in res.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'ORGANIZATION'):
    subtree_l=[]
    for leaf in subtree.leaves():
        subtree_l.append(leaf[0])
    sub = ' '.join(subtree_l)
    tree.append(sub)
print tree

Comment: do you know how to catch proper nouns with lower case prepositions embedded within them? e.g.: The David Eccles School of Business at the University of Utah

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely correct, but this will match most of what you are looking for, with the exception of `On`.

```
import re
text = """
#'On its 25th anniversary, Ashoka',

#'at the Shift Series national conference, Compass Partners and fashion designer Kenneth     
Cole',
"""
proper_noun_regex = r'([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,}(\s[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1,})?)'
p = re.compile(proper_noun_regex)
matches = p.findall(text)

print matches
```

output:

```
[('On', ''), ('Ashoka', ''), ('Shift Series', ' Series'), ('Compass Partners', ' Partners'), ('Kenneth Cole', ' Cole')]
```

And then maybe you could implement a filter to go over this list.

```
def filter_false_positive(unfiltered_matches):
    filtered_matches = []
    black_list = ["an","on","in","foo","bar"] #etc
    for match in unfiltered_matches:
        if match.lower() not in black_list:
            filtered_matches.append(match)
    return filtered_matches
```

or because python is cool:

```
def filter_false_positive(unfiltered_matches):
    black_list = ["an","on","in","foo","bar"] #etc
    return [match for match in filtered_matches if match.lower() not in black_list]
```

and you could use it like this:

```
# CONTINUED FROM THE CODE ABOVE
matches = [i[0] for i in matches]
matches = filter_false_positive(matches)
print matches
```

giving the final output:

```
['Ashoka', 'Shift Series', 'Compass Partners', 'Kenneth Cole']
```

The problem of determining whether a word is capitalized due to occuring at the beginning of the sentance or whether it is a proper noun is not that trivial.

```
'Kenneth Cole is a brand name.' v.s. 'Can I eat something now?' v.s. 'An English man had tea'
```

In this case it is pretty difficult, so without something that can know a proper noun by other standards, a black list, a database, etc. it won't be so easy.  `regex` is awesome but I don't think it can interpret English on a grammatical level in any trivial way...

That being said, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would use an NLP tool, the most popular for python seems to be [nltk](http://nltk.org). Regular expressions are really not the right way to go... There's an example on the frontpage of the nltk site, linked to earlier in the answer, which is copy-pasted below:

```
import nltk
sentence = """At eight o'clock on Thursday morning
... Arthur didn't feel very good."""
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)    
tokens
['At', 'eight', "o'clock", 'on', 'Thursday', 'morning',
'Arthur', 'did', "n't", 'feel', 'very', 'good', '.']
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
entities = nltk.chunk.ne_chunk(tagged)
```

entities now contains your words tagged according to [the Penn treebank](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html)